# How to sort data in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: sorting, azure-logic-apps

Is there way to sort data in Azure Logic apps? I want to Sort the list by their marks in descending order & Set the Class property values with Class = 1 for the highest marks, Class = 2 for the second highest and so on.

Comment: Do you have an example of your JSON?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a Transform XML Action with a Xslt that sorts the data.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that Logic Apps is a workflow engine, when it comes to data manipulation, I recommend send the data off to Azure Functions for processing, in which Logic Apps natively integrates with.